# Delphi - Button images suddenly not showing

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Delphi 11.1 Windows application, suddenly my TButtons with images are not displaying the images.  They normally don't display in debug mode, but now they're not showing in release mode.

These are TButton components with TImageList assigned and ImageIndex value assigned.  I have several TBitBtn components that are displaying properly.

First screenshot shows TButton with miscButtons chosen as images and ImageIndex 16.  The image shows in IDE. Second screenshot is running the application.  I already changed Go To Activity to TSpeedButton, so the image is working.

[image]

[image]

```
        object btnReqNewActivity: TButton
        Left = 141
        Top = 454
        Width = 175
        Height = 40
        Caption = 'Request NEW Activity'
        Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
        Font.Color = clWindowText
        Font.Height = -13
        Font.Name = 'Arial'
        Font.Style = []
        ImageIndex = 16
        ImageMargins.Left = 5
        Images = miscButtons
        ParentFont = False
        TabOrder = 1
        OnClick = btnReqNewActivityClick
      end
      object btnExportClassicList: TButton
        Left = 333
        Top = 454
        Width = 78
        Height = 40
        Caption = 'Export'
        Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
        Font.Color = clWindowText
        Font.Height = -13
        Font.Name = 'Arial'
        Font.Style = []
        ImageIndex = 4
        ImageMargins.Left = 5
        Images = miscButtons
        ParentFont = False
        TabOrder = 2
        OnClick = btnExportClassicListClick
      end
```

[image]

Comment: Because there is a bug... More seriously, provide some code that we can examine. Or even better, edit your question to provide a complete, simple example showing the issue.

Comment: There is no code to examine.  I have a TButton that uses a TImageList and an ImageIndex to display the image.  This worked fine but has suddenly stopped working. It is only affecting TButton, I had some TBitBtn that are working fine.

Comment: Have you checked the `.dfm` file? Are the images still there? Please provide the `.dfm` file and the `.pas` file for the form even if you don't have any other source file to provide. Probably nobody can help you if we can't reproduce the error. Therefore you must provide `.pas` and `.dfm` file. If the problem you claim cannot be reproduced with what you provide in your question, then there is no question/problem.

Comment: Here's a hint that I hope you follow: Links to external sites are not accepted, because they may become invalid at any time. All information that you want to provide to support your question must be posted within your question. You should visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read at least everything said about asking, before editing your question or asking a new one.

Comment: A membership for 6+ years should be enough to 1.) include code in the question and 2.) reduce it to a minimal reproducible example, instead of giving us 5500 lines of inconsistently indented PAS and 13963 lines of DFM.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I don't post here much so I wasn't aware.  AmigoJack, I wasn't sure what exactly was being asked for codewise, I was just told to provide the dfm and pas.

Comment: Thanks David for your edits. Two more details I ask you to provide: (1) the `.dfm` content for the three buttons as they are now (or were at the time of the run time image). (2) Which Project - Options - Appearance is selected?

Comment: @TomBrunberg - Done.  My app allows the user to choose from a handful of styles, I tried several different styles and same issue.

Comment: Can you try to create a new project and copy/past the Timagelist with the Tspeedbutton and the Tbutton, if you have the same problem, share this project with us

Comment: @Bosshoss - created new project, copied/pasted the imagelist, speedbutton and tbutton and it works fine.

Comment: And the dfm of your imagelist and button is the same than in your app ? I suggest you to remove imagelist and imageindex on your button , and then set it again

Comment: In your test project, have you set the style the same as the complete application? Styles are sometimes messing up drawing.

Comment: @fpiette yes, same style used in test app and works fine.  BossHoss - dfm of imagelist and button is the same in both.  I added a new ImageList with one image and a new button using the imageindex of the image in the new ImageList and the image does not show.  I'm changing out all the TButton for TBitBtn because those work.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem (Delphi 10.2): Added buttons weren't showing when the project was run.  Playing Devils Advocate, I found that no added visual components showed up (although the original ones still did).  Indeed, adding rubbish to the code didn't upset the compiler.

I had copied an entire directory and had definitely opened the project in the new directory.  Closing and opening the project showed the source with added buttons, but when running it they were gone!

I went back to the old directory, and there were my new buttons (and the project wouldn't run because of rubbish in the code).

Solution: I renamed the old directory, and was then able to edit the project in the new directory normally.  Somehow, after copying the old directory, Delphi was editing the version in the old directory, but running the one in the new directory!